# Why was the reconstructed error for one-hidden layer autoencoder much smaller than that of stacked autoencoders?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, autoencoders

I want to compare the reconstructed error from the traind autoencoder and stacked autoencoder within MATLAB. The following is my MATLAB code using the 'Deep Learning' toolbox:

```
load trainData.mat % 7-by-13457
%% Input
data = load([path, 'inPut\', 'trainData.mat']);
X = data.trainData;

%% Stacked autoencoder
hiddensz1 = 32;
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(X, hiddensz1,'MaxEpochs',400);
feature1 = encode(autoenc1, X);

hiddensz2 = 16;
autoenc2 = trainAutoencoder(feature1, hiddensz2,'MaxEpochs',400);
feature2 = encode(autoenc2, feature1);

%% decode1
XReconstructed1 = predict(autoenc1, X);
%% decode2
rfeature1 = decode(autoenc2, feature2);
XReconstructed2 = decode(autoenc1, rfeature1); % reconstructed input

mseError1 = mse(X - XReconstructed1);
mseError2 = mse(X - XReconstructed2);
```

The first error term '$mseError1$' was 5.9781, while the second error term '$mseError2$' is 190.0479. Why is the error from the shallow network is much smaller than that of stacked autoencoder? Could someone give some explanations on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're training your autoencoder one layer at a time, rather than end-to-end, so at best, even if the second layer could perfectly reconstruct the first layer features, the stacked autoencoder can be no better than the one-layer, and in practice, it's much worse.

Even if you did train the autoencoder end-to-end, your stacked model has half the dimensionality of the one-layer, so it wouldn't be surprising if it did worse.